# kubedns can't nslookup any service

Tags: kubernetes

version 1.6.1.I setup kubernetes with kubeadm.DNS cant resolve kubernetes service within heapster. But using ip of kubernetes is OK. Below is the container log of kubedns

```
[root@node-47 ~]# docker logs 624905719fa2
I0512 04:29:57.374905       1 dns.go:49] version: v1.5.2-beta.0+$Format:%h$
I0512 04:29:57.380148       1 server.go:70] Using configuration read from directory: /kube-dns-config%!(EXTRA time.Duration=10s)
I0512 04:29:57.380219       1 server.go:112] FLAG: --alsologtostderr="false"
I0512 04:29:57.380231       1 server.go:112] FLAG: --config-dir="/kube-dns-config"
I0512 04:29:57.380238       1 server.go:112] FLAG: --config-map=""
I0512 04:29:57.380242       1 server.go:112] FLAG: --config-map-namespace="kube-system"
I0512 04:29:57.380245       1 server.go:112] FLAG: --config-period="10s"
I0512 04:29:57.380268       1 server.go:112] FLAG: --dns-bind-address="0.0.0.0"
I0512 04:29:57.380272       1 server.go:112] FLAG: --dns-port="10053"
I0512 04:29:57.380278       1 server.go:112] FLAG: --domain="cluster.local."
I0512 04:29:57.380283       1 server.go:112] FLAG: --federations=""
I0512 04:29:57.380288       1 server.go:112] FLAG: --healthz-port="8081"
I0512 04:29:57.380292       1 server.go:112] FLAG: --initial-sync-timeout="1m0s"
I0512 04:29:57.380295       1 server.go:112] FLAG: --kube-master-url=""
I0512 04:29:57.380300       1 server.go:112] FLAG: --kubecfg-file=""
I0512 04:29:57.380303       1 server.go:112] FLAG: --log-backtrace-at=":0"
I0512 04:29:57.380309       1 server.go:112] FLAG: --log-dir=""
I0512 04:29:57.380315       1 server.go:112] FLAG: --log-flush-frequency="5s"
I0512 04:29:57.380318       1 server.go:112] FLAG: --logtostderr="true"
I0512 04:29:57.380323       1 server.go:112] FLAG: --nameservers=""
I0512 04:29:57.380326       1 server.go:112] FLAG: --stderrthreshold="2"
I0512 04:29:57.380330       1 server.go:112] FLAG: --v="2"
I0512 04:29:57.380334       1 server.go:112] FLAG: --version="false"
I0512 04:29:57.380340       1 server.go:112] FLAG: --vmodule=""
I0512 04:29:57.380386       1 server.go:175] Starting SkyDNS server (0.0.0.0:10053)
I0512 04:29:57.380816       1 server.go:197] Skydns metrics enabled (/metrics:10055)
I0512 04:29:57.380828       1 dns.go:147] Starting endpointsController
I0512 04:29:57.380832       1 dns.go:150] Starting serviceController
I0512 04:29:57.381406       1 logs.go:41] skydns: ready for queries on cluster.local. for tcp://0.0.0.0:10053 [rcache 0]
I0512 04:29:57.381417       1 logs.go:41] skydns: ready for queries on cluster.local. for udp://0.0.0.0:10053 [rcache 0]
I0512 04:29:57.439494       1 dns.go:264] New service: monitoring-influxdb
I0512 04:29:57.439579       1 dns.go:462] Added SRV record &{Host:monitoring-influxdb.kube-system.svc.cluster.local. Port:8086 Priority:10 Weight:10 Text: Mail:false Ttl:30 TargetStrip:0 Group: Key:}
I0512 04:29:57.439601       1 dns.go:462] Added SRV record &{Host:monitoring-influxdb.kube-system.svc.cluster.local. Port:8083 Priority:10 Weight:10 Text: Mail:false Ttl:30 TargetStrip:0 Group: Key:}
I0512 04:29:57.439623       1 dns.go:264] New service: dai-1-daiym-context-46
I0512 04:29:57.439642       1 dns.go:264] New service: kubernetes
I0512 04:29:57.439722       1 dns.go:462] Added SRV record &{Host:kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local. Port:443 Priority:10 Weight:10 Text: Mail:false Ttl:30 TargetStrip:0 Group: Key:}
I0512 04:29:57.439746       1 dns.go:264] New service: nginxservice
I0512 04:29:57.439766       1 dns.go:264] New service: heapster
I0512 04:29:57.439784       1 dns.go:264] New service: kube-dns
I0512 04:29:57.439803       1 dns.go:462] Added SRV record &{Host:kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local. Port:53 Priority:10 Weight:10 Text: Mail:false Ttl:30 TargetStrip:0 Group: Key:}
I0512 04:29:57.439818       1 dns.go:462] Added SRV record &{Host:kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local. Port:53 Priority:10 Weight:10 Text: Mail:false Ttl:30 TargetStrip:0 Group: Key:}
I0512 04:29:57.439834       1 dns.go:264] New service: kubernetes-dashboard
I0512 04:29:57.439851       1 dns.go:264] New service: monitoring-grafana
I0512 04:29:57.882534       1 dns.go:171] Initialized services and endpoints from apiserver
I0512 04:29:57.882995       1 server.go:128] Setting up Healthz Handler (/readiness)
I0512 04:29:57.883004       1 server.go:133] Setting up cache handler (/cache)
I0512 04:29:57.883009       1 server.go:119] Status HTTP port 8081
```

But I can't resolve any service within kubedns.

```
[root@node-47 ~]# docker exec -it 624905719fa2 sh
/ # nslookup nginxservice localhost
Server:    127.0.0.1
Address 1: 127.0.0.1 localhost

nslookup: can't resolve 'nginxservice': Try again
/ # nslookup heapster localhost
Server:    127.0.0.1
Address 1: 127.0.0.1 localhost

nslookup: can't resolve 'heapster': Try again
```

Comment: why do you use `localhost` as dns server? Did you try `nslookup nginxserver`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use full DNS name of service try again if service do not have the same namespace with DNS? Check https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/ to get full dns name.